# How to make a partially hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a half shown div in a page, like a footer. When I click it I want it to slide up. The div will contain information on it.

I achieved this somehow, but my problem is that the div does not get really hidden it just changes the position.

You can find the demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/394/

```
var clicked=false;
$(".two").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".two").css({"bottom": -430});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".two").css({"bottom": "-200px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: define `hidden`. can adjust height with overflow hidden if that is what's wanted

Comment: Hidden to not be shown on the page at all, just when I clicked on that small shown part, then I want it to slide up and show.

Comment: well thats a lot different than `partialy hidden` that was stated in question and subject. Please update question with specifics

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/396/ ? It starts half hidden (actually a little more) and when you click it, it gets full visible.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pmtg19ab/

Comment: So the red square represents the page right? And on actual note page it will work right ?! If so then yes that is what I want

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1d6omsyq/ ?

Comment: Yes, that red square is the whole page, but you must put all the content inside `.container`. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141392/how-to-make-a-partially-hidden-div/#answer-28141608)s this question entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while ago, in fact I think it was my first stackoverflow question. Unfortunately it got poorly received.

Anyway, the problem is currently that you *are* just changing the position of the div - that's what `.bottom` does. I think what you want to do is change the height, see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/397/) in which I managed to switch the div between states (no animation yet).

It makes simple use of css's [`overflow-y: hidden;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) to hide the div's contents when it is small, and all the JS does is toggle between heights:

```
if(clicked)
{
    $(".two").css("height", 10);
}
else
{
    $(".two").css("height", 250);
}
clicked = !clicked;
```

`clicked = !clicked` just flips the boolean state of the variable.

Now, to add the animation, we can use jQuery's [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and produce [this beautiful Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/399/)

Basically, all we had to do in between is use animate instead of css. Simple, really.

**TL;DR**
[final JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/399/)

Comment: I already accept one answer. But, this one is very well explained answer. Thank you

Comment: @AhmedHMehiny I don't understand - the other answer will cause a lot of problems in more complex websites, this one actually stays within the window. But okay, great question :)

Answer (score 2):

`.two` must be absolute positioned inside `.container` that must be relative positioned. Then you just change the `bottom` with a negative value and that will hide the footer.

**CSS:**

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.two {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height:250px;
    bottom: -200px;
    transition: bottom 1s;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var clicked=false;
$(".two").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".two").css({"bottom": "-200px"});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".two").css({"bottom": 0});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/398/

Comment: ฏ๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎